# Error in WKWatchOnly key for WatchConnectivity

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, watchconnectivity

message: The WKWatchOnly key must not be present in your WatchKit extension's Info.plist because your WatchKit app is embedded in an iOS companion app.
How can i change this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to your target list
- Select your WatchKit Extension
- Select tab [Build Settings]
- Search for keyword "**WKWatchOnly**"
- Change the value of `App is Available Only on Apple Watch` to `No`

Here is the screenshot for better understanding: [Update WatchKit Extension setting for WKWatchOnly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycgox.png)

Hope that you solve your problem.